# PHP programming in iPad

Tags: php, ide, ios, ipad

I want to develop some PHP applications on my iPad device but there is 2 problems! First , i can not find any local server applications on iPad like Wamp or Lamp, and second my Googling only returns Cloud based IDEs for this!!! any idea?

Comment: Coming up next: 'PHP programming on Amazon Kindle'

Comment: Hi Vahid Asefi, setting up a LAMP environment is off-topic here, but it looks like you're a bit confused about what the iPad is actually capable of: I suggest reading the [Wikipedia article on the iPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad) to get a better understanding of the device.

Comment: @VahidAsefi Check out this [discussion](http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-hacking/24007-running-php-server-ipad.html), it's possible to have PHP on the iPad after all.

Comment: Since this question is closed I can't post this as an answer but Kodiak does what th OP asked for... http://www.becomekodiak.com/

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you're looking to actually do full-blown PHP development on an iPad I highly suggest you don't.  Mostly because it isn't possible.  There's no way to install Apache, MySQL or PHP on to an iPad.  The best you'd be able to do is get an iPad specific "IDE", like [Gusto](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gusto/id364906873?mt=8) that allows you to FTP into sites and do some basic code maintenance.  Again, not really suitable for full-blown development.

Some things the iPad can't replace.  Any kind of serious development work certainly falls into this category.

Comment: Well, that's not really the *best* you can do since there's nothing stopping you from using a text editor like VIM remotely.  [This guy did it](http://yieldthought.com/post/12239282034/swapped-my-macbook-for-an-ipad).

Comment: According to the OP's question they were looking for a full-blown, web-server **on** the iPad.  If you're just gonna connect to a cloud based IDE and do everything through the cloud you could just as easily do it on a smartphone.  Doesn't change the fact that you can't install an *AMP stack on an iOS device.

Comment: That's true, but I wasn't responding to that.  I was responding to "the best you'd be able to do is ... FTP into sites and do some basic code maintenance".  You can do more than FTP and basic code maintenance with SSH and VIM.